# User Permissions for WAL files

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-9.4, windows-server

I'm setting up replication on Postgres. (expect more questions later :-)
I'm putting the WAL files on the NAS so that both servers have access to the files.
The Postgres service is running as "NETWORK SERVICE".

I trying to set permissions on the WAL directory so that the primary can write and both servers can read the files.

Security currently lists "Domain Admins" and "Domain" Users" as having access to the folder.
Trying to add "NETWORK SERVICE" isn't recognized.
If I add "NAS\NETWORK SERVICE", it disappears immediately.

Checking Effect Access still shows that "NAS\NETWORK SERVICE" has no access to the folder.

I assume that "NETWORK SERVICE" is a local user rather than a domain user and isn't going to be able to access the files on the network.
Should I create a user just to run the Postgres servers, or is there an easier way?

Comment: Apart from the permissions problem, you will likely pay a severe performance penalty by placing WAL files on a network drive. If you want to give the other server access to them, configure archiving to a NAS volume, but keep the actual WAL local.

Comment: @mustaccio  "configure archiving to a NAS volume, but keep the actual WAL local" I'm pretty sure that that is what he *is* doing.

Comment: This really seems like a question for your storage administrator.  For a DBA, I think the answer would be 1) ask the Windows storage administrator and/or 2) use streaming not log shipping.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.4 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: "*Should I create a user just to run the Postgres server*" - that's probably a good idea anyway. Another option is to use streaming replication, then you don't need to write the WAL files to a shared network drive.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  Upgrading is next on my list. One step lower priority than getting the failover working. I tried upgrading first because the capabilities have changed and are probably more robust. But that failed and I haven't been able to track down the issue yet. So failover will get done first.

Comment: @jjanes Yes, it is the archive command that tries to copy them over. The WAL files are already written. This is just archiving them as you expected.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  You are correct that streaming is the better option. I'm on this step: "To use streaming replication, [first] set up a file-based log-shipping standby server as described in Section 27.2." Once I have this working, I'll try to switch over to streaming.